# Python - Average similar values in list and create new list with averaged values

Tags: python, list

I have lists with many numbers which can include decimals. For example,

```
A = ['1', '1.01', '1.1', '2', '3', '3.2', '4', '5']
```

Let's say I want to get an average of those terms which differ by less than 0.5, and make a new list with those averaged terms, plus the ones which were unaffected.

In my example, the numbers 1, 1.01 and 1.1 differ by less than 0.5 to each other, so the new list would include the average of them, 1,04. Similarly, for 3 and 3.2, the new list would include the average 3,1.

So the final output would be:

```
B = [1.04, 2, 3.1, 4, 5]
```

There are some special cases, such as the list

```
C = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6]
```

where certain questions arise: do we average the first 5 elements, or the last 5? If it is possible, I prefer a priority from left to right, that is, group the first 5 elements and keep the sixth one. **However**, it is very unlikely that the data in my lists will show such behavior, because the similar values are sufficiently close to each other. It is not really necessary to include these cases in the code, unless it is a must for it to work properly.

What is the most efficient way to do this? In practice, I'm going to use this to construct the lightcurves for different supernovae. If the difference in time between two observations is less than certain value, I may aswell consider it as a single observation made on an average time between both.

I am fairly new to Python, and all my efforts to solve this problem have failed so far... my apologies if this is too basic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does the number 5 come from in your `C` example? How will you know that 1.04 in the `B` example is the average of 3 terms and not a solitary entry; how will you know the timecode for 3.1 when you don't know how the observations have been coalesced?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped an extra term in my C example. I think it is clearer now that the first 5 terms differ by less than 0.5 from eachother, so do the last 5 terms. I'm only averaging once for each list, and the values I obtain after using the code will be considered as the dates of observation. This will not affect the general shape of the plot I want to obtain. A small diference in the decimals of those numbers means that one observation was made a few minutes or hours laters than the other one, and in practice can be considered on the same day. The values in my lists are actually Julian Days.

Comment: Does elements in list must be stings?

Comment: The output elements in lists have to be floats so I can plot them directly. In my example I wrote A as a list of strings but don't worry about that, I may aswell convert all elements to floats before applying the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are obviously a number of ways to solve this.  I would like to share an alternative approach that uses a `grouper` function and the standard library.  I have also defined a convenience function `average_similar`.  Example usage:

```
# Convert, sort and group.  Print generated groups.
A = ['1', '1.01', '1.1', '2', '3', '3.2', '4', '5']
a1 = sorted(float(f) for f in A)
g1 = grouper(a1)

print("Grouped A:", g1)
# Grouped A: [[1.0, 1.01, 1.1], [2.0], [3.0, 3.2], [4.0], [5.0]]


# Generate new list as average of each group.
g2 = (mean(g) for g in grouper(a1))
a2 = list(g2)

print("Averaged grouped A:", a2)
# Averaged grouped A: [1.0366666666666668, 2.0, 3.1, 4.0, 5.0]

print("Averaged grouped A:", average_similar(A, width=0.5))
# Averaged grouped A: [1.0366666666666668, 2.0, 3.1, 4.0, 5.0]


# Generate new list as rounded averages of each group.
g3 = (round(mean(g), 2) for g in grouper(a1))
a3 = list(g3)

print("Averaged grouped and rounded A:", a3)
# Averaged grouped and rounded A: [1.04, 2.0, 3.1, 4.0, 5.0]

print("Averaged grouped and rounded A:", average_similar(A, 0.5, 2))
# Averaged grouped and rounded A: [1.04, 2.0, 3.1, 4.0, 5.0]


# A more compact example given a list of numbers.
C = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4]
# In-place sort.
C.sort() 
lc = list(round(mean(g), 2) for g in grouper(C))
print("Average C", lc)
# Average C [1.3, 1.6]
print("Average C", average_similar(C, precision=2))
# Average C [1.3, 1.6]


# Another examples as a one-liner.
D = ['1', '1.01', '1.1', '2', '3', '3.2', '4', '5', '5.1', '6', '2.5']
ld = list(round(mean(g), 2)
          for g in grouper(
                  sorted(float(f) for f in D)))
print("Average D", ld)
# Average D [1.04, 2.0, 2.5, 3.1, 4.0, 5.05, 6.0]
print("Average D", average_similar(D, width=0.5, precision=2))
# Average D [1.04, 2.0, 2.5, 3.1, 4.0, 5.05, 6.0]
```

These exempels use the following code:

```
import itertools
from statistics import mean

def average_similar(iterable, width=0.5, precision=None, criteria=make_keyfcn):
    """Return a list where similar numbers have been averaged.

    Items are grouped using the supplied width and criteria and the
    result is rounded to precision if it is supplied.  Otherwise
    averages are not rounded.

    """
    lst = sorted(float(f) for f in iterable)
    g1 = (mean(g) for g in grouper(lst, criteria(width)))
    if precision is not None:
      g1 = (round(g, precision) for g in g1)
    return list(g1)

def grouper(iterable, criteria=None):
    if criteria is None:
        criteria = make_keyfcn()
    result = []
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(iterable, criteria):
        result.append(list(g))
    return result

def make_keyfcn(width=0.5):
    "Grouping critera."
    key = None
    def keyfcn(x):
        """As long as x is < key, keep returning key.

        Update when x >= key.
        """
        nonlocal key
        if key is None:  # When called the first time.
            key = x + width
        elif x >= key:
            key = x + width
        return key
    return keyfcn
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is a very interesting approach and it seems to work very well.

Comment: Glad you like it.  Note how `average_similar` enables independent variability for width, precision and criteria.

Answer (score 4):

```
A = [1, 1.01, 1.1, 2, 3, 3.2, 4, 5]
groups, current_group, first = [], [], A[0]
for item in A:
    # Check if this element falls under the current group
    if item - first <= 0.5:
        current_group.append(item)
    else:
        # If it doesn't, create a new group and add old to the result
        groups.append(current_group[:])
        current_group, first = [item], item
# Add the last group which was being gathered to the result
groups.append(current_group[:])
```

Now, its fairly straightforward to get the average, like this

```
print[sum(item) / len(item) for item in groups]
# [1.0366666666666666, 2, 3.1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This splits clusters like `[0.9, 1.0, 1.1]`.

Comment: Doesn't work if the input is out of order.. Not sure if that's required though.

Comment: @PokeyMcPokerson We might have to sort it then.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and dedication. I'm not sure why, but when I apply this code to one of my lists, I end up with a list which, apart from the averaged value, includes a value of the older group. For example, here is one input list:

[51305.0, 51308.06, 51309.0, 51309.01, 51312.97, 51317.02, 51317.04, 51318.96, 51320.96, 51322.0, 51326.96, 51328.96, 51330.96]

And your code yields:

[51305.0, 51308.06, 51309.0, 51309.005000000005, 51312.97, 51317.02, 51317.03, 51318.96, 51320.96, 51322.0, 51326.96, 51328.96, 51330.96]

Please note that I changed the limiting value to 0.25 instead of 0.5

Comment: @Kike Can you please let me know what is wrong with that result?

Comment: @thefourtheye In my input, the terms 51309.0 and 51309.01 differ by less than 0.25. I'd like to compute the average of those two terms, and include only that average to the new list. However, the output I get includes 51309.0 and 51309.005000000005. I only need the average on the new list, so 51309.0 should not be there. The same is the case for the numbers 51317.02 and 51317.04.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer by 
@thefourtheye is better than this one.

```
A = ['1', '1.01', '1.1', '2', '3', '3.2', '4', '5']
# change str to float and sort it.
a = sorted([float(v) for v in A])

averaged_start = a[0]

averaged_dict = {}
for value in a:
    if value - averaged_start < 0.5:
        averaged_dict.setdefault(averaged_start, []).append(value)
    else:
        averaged_start = value
        averaged_dict[averaged_start] = [averaged_start]

result = [round(sum(v)/len(v), 2) for k, v in averaged_dict.items()]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1.04, 2.0, 3.1, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm getting the following error when I run this code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maker.py", line 85, in <module>
    result[averaged_start] = [averaged_start]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float

Comment: I am sorry, I use `result` to delegate two different thing. One is dict, the other is list, This  is confusing.  I have changed my code, use `averaged_dict` to delegate that dict. The code is OK now.

Answer (score 0):

Just after making my question, someone responded to it with the following code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

A = [1, 1.01, 1.02, 2, 3, 4, 4,4.1]

d = OrderedDict()

for item in A:
    d.setdefault(int(item/0.25), []).append(item)

    A = [sum(item) / len(item) for item in d.itervalues()]

print A
#[1.01, 2, 3, 4.033333333333333]
```

So far, this code works very good, although I haven't tested every detail of it. Thanks to whoever posted it and deleted it afterwards!